# Is adventurers league still restricting rules for character creation to PHB + 1?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league

There are [several](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/141333/does-limiting-the-number-of-sources-help-simplify-the-game-for-a-new-dm-with-new) [questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122731/does-the-phb1-character-building-limit-in-adventurers-league-include-spells) that indicate that Wizards of the Coast's organized play outlet for D&D 5e, Adventurer's League, restricts character creation to the Player's Handbook and only ONE optional rulebook (you choose which one).

E.g. you could use the PHB and Xanathar's Guide to Everything, or the PHB and Tasha's Cauldron of Everything, but not all three of them.

I think this is a wise rule, as it allows making use of all the content, and at the same time limits the nearly unavoidable emergence of broken combinations that can arise when combining ever more features and abilities in unforeseen ways.

However, looking at the [Player's Guide document](https://media.wizards.com/2021/dnd/downloads/DDAL_PlayersGuidev11_0.pdf) from the [WotC AL site](https://dnd.wizards.com/ddal_general), I see no such limitation. Right on page 1, it says

> WHAT RULEBOOKS SHOULD I USE? You can use  non-optional  rules  found  in  the  Player’s  Handbook, the  Basic  Rules,  and  all  the  books  listed  below.

and then continues to list out pretty much everything, Volo's, Tasha's, Mordenkainen's, Fizbans, and so on.

Can someone clarify if the PHB + 1 guideline is still in effect?

Comment: The appropriate way to call more attention to the existing question here is to offer a bounty—one of the options for why you’re offering a bounty is to seek up-to-date information.

Comment: I was not trying to call attention to it, I was looking for someone to answer. I had searched and had not found the linked answer (it does not contain the clause "PHB + 1"). Having it closed with a link to the existing answer is perfectly fine for my needs.

Comment: Fair enough, my impression based on what you were describing about other answers on this site was that you had already seen it. Anyway, I would point out that the answer in that question is over a year old, so if you want the most up-to-date answer you may *want* to draw attention to it.

Comment: @KRyan would it be OK to edit its title to inlcude the "PHB +1" phrase? that might help

Comment: That sounds good to me but I’m not very invested or involved in that question, so that’s a question better posed to, say, @nitsua60 who asked it.

Comment: I feel slightly weird about closing this as the target Q&A, as the answer here is the reason we closed that one. However, if this resolves the issue and provides a path to that Q for those who'd search with "PHB + 1", then *this* Q is doing dupe as intended, ie. being a pointer to the answer using the other wording.

Comment: I do not have the ability to update the linked answer, but it is out of date. As of Season 11, the +1 rule no longer applies.